# SQL Server : query columns to JSON object with group by

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns, I want to query that table such that the result will be a JSON object.

Sample data looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE #Test (ValueV INT, KEYS NVARCHAR (100), ID INT) 

 INSERT INTO #Test 
 VALUES (1, N'ChangeAdress 19 - 21', 200),
        (1, N'ChangeAdress 20 - 22', 200),
        (1, N'ChangeAdress 22 - 24', 300),
        (1, N'ChangeAdress 23 - 25', 300),
        (2, N'ChangeAdress 24 - 26', 400),
        (2, N'ChangeAdress 25 - 27', 400),
        (3, N'ChangeAdress 26 - 28', 400),
        (3, N'ChangeAdress 27 - 29', 400)

 SELECT * FROM #Test
```

My query attempt:

```
 SELECT ID, Keys, ValueV
 FROM #Test  
 GROUP BY ID, keys, ValueV
 FOR JSON AUTO
```

But that returns 1 JSON 'row'. What I want, is one row per group. Group being here ID, Value combination. I have little experience with JSON objects (which is probably visible from this query), so help would be appreciated.

The desired output (but then as JSON per row):

```
 --------------------------------------------------
|200, 1, ChangeAdress 19 - 21, ChangeAdress 20 - 22|
|300, 1, ChangeAdress 22 - 24, ChangeAdress 23 - 25|
|400, 2, ChangeAdress 24 - 26, ChangeAdress 25 - 27|
|400, 3, ChangeAdress 26 - 28, ChangeAdress 27 - 29|
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Output not clear. What you've got now is not JSON. Do you want something like `{ "ID": 200,  "ValueV": 1, "KEYS": ["ChangeAdress 19-21", "ChangeAdress 20-22"] }`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert If that is regular JSON format, then yes. I lack familiarity here with JSON objects, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for your good question. I also came across this question exactly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works (in SQL Server 2017, where `STRING_AGG` is available), but is quite clumsy. I'm not sure there's not a more elegant way.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT 
       ID, 
       ValueV, 
       Keys = JSON_QUERY('["' + STRING_AGG(STRING_ESCAPE(Keys, 'json'), '","') + '"]')
    FOR JSON PATH
)
FROM #Test 
GROUP BY ID, ValueV
```

For SQL Server 2016 (which has no `STRING_AGG`, or `STRING_ESCAPE` for that matter):

```
SELECT (
    SELECT ID, ValueV, Keys = JSON_QUERY(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        (
            SELECT Keys 
            FROM #Test t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.ValueV = t1.ValueV 
            FOR JSON PATH
        ),
        '{"Keys":', ''),
        '}', ''))
    FOR JSON PATH
)
FROM #Test t1
GROUP BY ID, ValueV
```

Even less elegant, but you take what you can get. At least we're not concatenating with `FOR XML`...

Comment: My problem was solved only by the fact that you can "select" again in the "select" format in "json" format, and finally with "group by" to avoid duplicate lines or use "distinct".

Comment: What you do if you want the result in a single json?

Comment: What if we want to combine multiple columns values to single JSON object?

Answer (score 7):

Posting this if any one has the same sort of use case

```
SELECT [t].[ID], 
(SELECT [t1].[KEYS], [t1].[ValueV] FROM @Test t1 WHERE t1.[ID] = [t].id FOR JSON PATH ) a
FROM @Test AS [t]
GROUP BY [t].[ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

My two cents:

Interesting that you want valid individual JSON rows and not one single JSON string. Anyhow, here are some alternate answers, although the accepted answer is the best one.

```
-- 100% hardcoded yourself. Pre SQL Server 2016 
SELECT '[{"ID":' + convert(nvarchar(4),T1.[ID]) + ',"ValueV":' + convert(nvarchar(4),T1.[ValueV]) + ',"Keys":["' + T1.[Keys] + '","' + T2.[Keys] + '"]}]' AS [keys]
FROM #Test AS T1 INNER JOIN #Test T2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.ValueV = t1.ValueV AND t2.keys > t1.keys
```

Or:

```
-- Use the OPENJSON to output your results as a dataset and not just a single row. I've removed the escape character back slashes to match the accepted answers output  
    SELECT 
     '[' + REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE([value], '\','')),':"[',':[')),']"}',']}') + ']'
    FROM OPENJSON(
    (SELECT T1.[ID],T1.[ValueV], '["' + T1.[Keys] + '","' + T2.[Keys] + '"]' AS [keys]
    FROM #Test AS T1 INNER JOIN #Test T2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.ValueV = t1.ValueV AND t2.keys > t1.keys 
    FOR JSON PATH))
```

Or:

```
-- This is a lot cleaner for an array of values in pairs. Again using OPENJSON to output your desired result.  
select 
'[' + [Value] + ']' FROM OPENJSON(
(select T1.[ID], T1.[ValueV], JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY('[]','append lax $',t0.keys),'append lax $',t1.keys) as keys
FROM #Test AS T0 inner join #Test as t1
on  t0.ID = t1.ID AND t0.ValueV = t1.ValueV AND t0.keys < t1.keys
FOR JSON path))
```

Just quick a note that JSON itself is not an object, but just a string of named value pairs, valid JavaScript but a subset nonetheless, it looks completely different when for instance you want a nested Javascript object (If JS is your intended data destination, I'm assuming here). The JSON function's great for quickly pulling off data for transfer, but when you want a nested output or grouping the dataset for an array of values not objects, it can become quite tricky. Personally, since it's a string, for more complicated stuff I just build it myself. Hope that's a different take.

Comment: thanks for adding some options. It's been a while since I posted this, but you still put in some effort, great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT [ID], [Keys], [ValueV]  FOR JSON PATH)
FROM #Test 
GROUP BY ID, keys, ValueV
```

or this:

```
SELECT (SELECT [ID], [Keys], [ValueV]  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM #Test 
GROUP BY ID, keys, ValueV
```

Comment: Thanks. This points in the right direction. However, in this example I want 4 rows returned. Your query's return 8.

Answer (score 1):

You might do:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT ID, ValueV, KEYS
 FROM Test Test2
 WHERE (Test2.ValueV = Test.ValueV AND Test2.ID = Test.ID) FOR JSON PATH) JSON
FROM Test
GROUP BY ValueV, ID
```

Or in to keep the grouping columns out of the JSON column :

```
SELECT 
ID, ValueV,
(SELECT KEYS
 FROM Test Test2
 WHERE (Test2.ValueV = Test.ValueV AND Test2.ID = Test.ID) FOR JSON PATH) JSON
FROM Test
GROUP BY ValueV, ID
```