# Create a view from a table from multiple rows to generate a JSON column group by specified column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using Azure sql:
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion');

returns:
12.0.2000.8

I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProperty](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserProperty]([UserId], [Key], [Value])
VALUES(1, 'hello', 'world'),
(1, 'ja', 'va'),
(2, 'hello', 'world'),
(2, 'csh', 'arp'),
(2, 'machine', 'learning');
GO
```

And I want to create a view which as follow:

```
| UserId | JsonValue | <br>
|--------|--------|<br>
| 1 | {"hello":"world", "ja":"va"} | <br>
| 2 | {"hello":"world", "csh":"arp", "machine":"learning"} |
```

I want to get a view like this

[image]

Comment: Tag the DBMS version that you are currently working.

Comment: I am using Azure sql: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion');

returns: 12.0.2000.8

Comment: I think one of my recent questions was quite similar, you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574006/sql-server-query-columns-to-json-object-with-group-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd think that SQL Server's native JSON facilities would be more useful here, but not really -- some clumsy string concatenation required, and the only thing we really benefit from is native escaping for JSON. This is because there's not really any convenient way to map columns into key/value pairs; simple column-as-key mappings only.

```
SELECT [UserID], JsonValue = 
    '{' + STRING_AGG(
        '"' + STRING_ESCAPE([key], 'json') + '"' + ':' + 
        '"' + STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json') + '"',
        ','
    ) + '}'
FROM UserProperty
GROUP BY UserID
```

This requires SQL Server 2017+; it should also work on Azure since that's ahead of the curve.

Comment: @LanHuanze: if this answer works for you, consider accepting it by using the checkmark just below the down arrow.